# Cannot POST in Express + Passport app

Tags: node.js, express, post, passport.js

I've read similar questions, but I couldn't find a solution.

In my `server.js` file:

```
var express         = require('express');
var app             = express();
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var passport        = require('passport');
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession  = require('express-session');
var passportHelp    = require('./config/passport');
var flash           = require('connect-flash');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './app/views'))  
app.use(expressSession({ 
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true 
}));
passportHelp(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash()); 
app.use(require('./app/controllers')); 
app.listen(3000);
```

In ./app/controllers

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.use(require('./signup'));
module.exports = router;
```

In ./controllers/signup

```
var express = require('express');  
var passport = require('passport');  
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {  
  res.render('signup');
});
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {  
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/signup',
  failureFlash: true,
}));
module.exports = router;
```

Finally, in ./config/passport

```
 var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
 var User            = require('../app/models/user');
 module.exports = function(passport) {
     passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
         done(null, user.id);
     });
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

 passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true 
    },
  function(req, username, password, done) {
     console.log(req.body.username);
     console.log(req.body.password); //successfully logs all of these 3
     console.log(req.body.email);
      process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, function(err, user) {           
            if (err) {
                return done(err);    
            }           
            if (user) { 
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } 
            else {                    
                var newUser = new User;
               //filling new user data here
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });    
    });
}));
```

I end up with strange behavior. Sometimes `POST` has no problem, sometimes I get `cannot POST /signup`, but the result is still saved into the database. 
I've tried switching some lines in `server.js` file, but without result. As I've read, when I `require passport` in `controller/signup`, it should be the same 'passport' object which I 'initialized' in `server.js`, so I dont end up working with a fresh `passport` object. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone faces the same problem.
The reason I got the error, but the save into the database was successful was that I have commented that line:  `successRedirect`